# Finding distance to nearest school from buildings with Geopandas

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geopandas

I want to calculate the distances of the nearest school from buildings of a particular geographical area and then categorize the distance values (for example 0-100, 100-200, and so on) The data source used is OpenStreetMap (OSM).

Firstly, I stored the buildings and school data in two separate geodataframes and tried to adopt the solution from ([Calculate Distance to Nearest Feature with Geopandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740046/calculate-distance-to-nearest-feature-with-geopandas)). But I've been getting some error.

This problem is different in the sense that both the geodataframes contain multiple types of geometries i.e. **points**(nodes in OSM) and **polygons**(ways in OSM).

Comment: Please add your code, what did you tried and also share the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have buiding_df and school_df are the two dataframe for building, school respectively. Now you can calculate the distancess of the nearest school from buildings of a particular area by using following code,

```py
def nearest_school(building_df, school_df):
    return school_df.distance(building_df).min()

buildings_utm['nearest_school_distance'] = building_df.geometry.apply(nearest_school, args=(school_df,))
```